# Как завершить все запушенные экземпляры/процессы bat файла

Tags: python

Как завершить все запушенные экземпляры/процессы bat файла.

делаю так:

```
subprocess.Popen(r"C:/Users/Windows10/Desktop/bot_run.bat")
os.system("taskkill /f /im bot_run.bat")
```

но не помогает.
Даже пробовал так: `os.system("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe")` не помог.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не забываем читать [Документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), и многие вопросы просто не будут возникать

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(r"C:/Users/Windows10/Desktop/bot_run.bat")
proc.kill() # proc.terminate()
```